# Recycler View doesn't load again

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, fragment, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase UI and a Recycler View inside a Fragment.

When I create this fragment and the recycler view loads all the info from firestore, but once I lock and unlock my phone it just dissapears.

Once I inflate the fragment layout I do this:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.view = view; //View of the fragment
    setupRecyclerView(); // Get the recycler 
    loadData(); //Loads data into the recycler
}
```

This is the method where I get the recycler view from the inflated layout:

```
public void setupRecyclerView(){
    //Recycler
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
}
```

This is the method "loadData":

```
public void loadData(){

    //Query
    Query query = fStore.collection("users");

    //RecyclerOptions
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setQuery(query, User.class)
                .build();

    //RecyclerAdapter
    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(options)
    {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            System.out.println("view holder");
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_file, parent, false);
            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull User model)
        {
            holder.listName.setText(model.getName());

        }
    };

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Lifecycles:

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("Started");
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    System.out.println("Stopped");
    adapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

I also tried to loadData onResume cycle and doesn't work, even if I start the app again.
I'm pretty sure it will happen the same if I go to other activity and comeback to this.

Question: Why the RecyclerView doesn't load the items again? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: Thank you @AlexMamo !! This solved my issue, but what does setHasFixedSize do to cause this problem?